# How can I get json data from a url using this.$http.get()?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I am new to vuejs, please help me out on this-

```
this.$http.get() is not working.
```

I tried -

```
npm install vue-resource
```

and

```
npm install vue-resource --save
```

Then I wrote this code

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        {{ questionData }}
    </v-container>
</template>



data () {
return {
  questionData: [],



mounted () {
 this.$http.get('http://api.iqube.org.in/questions').then(response => {

    this.questionData = response.body;
    console.log(response.body)
  }, error => {

  });
}
```

Console log shows undefined.

This is what my main.js looks like

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

import './plugins/vuetify';
import './plugins/axios';

import './registerServiceWorker';

import App from './App.vue';

import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Am I importing something that is not required?

All the questions data should show in the page. But I am getting a blank page. I also get this error in console

```
Cannot redefine property: $http
```

Comment: axios is a library that is commonly used for GET, POST, and other actions. You might want to take a look at it. ofc it might be unnecessary at simpler service requests, but it will simplify your code a lot due to its response parsing capabilities.

Comment: "Console log shows undefined." console.log shows **what** is undefined?

Comment: @ceejayoz most likely `response.body`

Comment: @mcy Very possible, and I'd bet OP needs to use `response.data` instead there.

Comment: I am still getting this error:     vue-resource.esm.js?28dd:1520 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $http
    at Function.defineProperties (<anonymous>)
    at plugin (vue-resource.esm.js?28dd:1520)
    at Function.Vue.use (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5103)
    at eval (main.js?56d7:14)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:7574)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at Object.1 (app.js:7948)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at app.js:791

Comment: https://github.com/boidurja/mobileAppOnGithub.git This is the link to my project in github. Can anyone find out the problem? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging your app i found that you re-defied (re-imported) `Vue`on your `dailypractice.vue` component also `VueAxios`/ `axios`... if you are going to use `vueResource` you don't need `axios` (i reccomend axios as a Vue dev )

```
// dailypractice.vue
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import axios from 'axios'
  import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
  Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

**Just remove the previous code from your `dailypractice` component and also `axios` / `VueAxios` from your project (axios.js file) and your app will work fine.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `this.$http` root :

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import App from './App.vue';

import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

 Vue.http.options.root = 'http://api.iqube.org.in/';
```

then on your mounted and wherever you include `this.$http` add the route that you want to target ... like this :

```js
mounted () {
    this.$http.get('/questions').then(response => {
    this.questionData = response.body;
    console.log(response.body)
    }, error => {

  });
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/boidurja/mobileAppOnGithub.git This is the link to my project in github. Can anyone find out the problem? I would be very grateful.

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar yes bro i will check your issue now .. and post another answer with the solution to it

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget import axios and use it at *main.js* .

```
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(axios)
```